# It is possible to assign different Gtk themes to certain applications?

Tags: 12.04, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use different GTK3 themes for individual apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-use-different-gtk3-themes-for-individual-apps)

For example, can I keep Ambiance as main theme but assign elementary theme to elementary's app?