# Set variable in .desktop file

Tags: unity, launcher, environment-variables

Is there a way to set the enviroment variable in .desktop file?
I'm trying to run application (eclipse) with custom gtk style, so basically I want to get the following result by runing a .desktop file:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=gtkrc.custom /path/to/eclipse
```

I've tryied to put it in a bash script and run it from the .desktop file, but then it does not integrate well with the Unity launcher.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You can add an environment variable to an application by editing its `.desktop` file. For example, to run "digiKam" with the environment variable `APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1`, find the corresponding `digikam.desktop` file and add the setting of the variable, via the `env` command, to the entry "Exec":

```sh
Exec=env APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1 digikam -caption "%c" %i
```

In your case:

```sh
Exec=env GTK2_RC_FILES=gtkrc.custom /path/to/eclipse
```

Comment: how can I set env variable containing user's `$HOME`?. Neither `Exec=env MYVAR="$HOME/foo"` nor `Exec=env MYVAR="~/foo"` gets expanded. Instead, they are passed literally.

Comment: it seems you can do it as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980518/1446479

Comment: for other looking for a slight variation on this, you can also unset env vars with the `-u` flag, like `env -u DONT_WANT_THIS_SET some-command`

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to modify the `.desktop` file is to put a wrapper script in e.g. `~/bin`.

```sh
$ cat ~/bin/eclipse
#!/bin/sh
export GTK2_RC_FILES=gtkrc.custom
exec /usr/bin/eclipse "$@"
```

This way the customization won't be overwritten next time the application package is updated.

*Edit:*

A hint about why this works can you see by checking out what the `PATH` variable contains. In my case:

```sh
$ echo $PATH
/home/gunnar/bin:/home/gunnar/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

`~/bin` is the first folder in the list, and thus is looked at before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: If you just put your .desktop file in your local settings, it won't get overridden, anyway.

Comment: @Auspex: True. But at the same time, if you use a local copy, you won't benefit from possible updates of the package owned `.desktop` file.

Comment: I'm not seeing how putting a wrapper in `~/bin` is going to help with that. The package-owned `.desktop` file is never going to see that wrapper! You'd need to also use `update-alternatives`

Comment: @Auspex: The `.desktop` file does not need to "see" the wrapper. It just executes `eclipse`, and due to `PATH` the wrapper is picked instead of `/usr/bin/eclipse`. I edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: Yes, the .desktop file _does_ need to see the wrapper. I was thinking that the average .desktop file specifies a full path, but on further inspection I think most of the system ones do just specify a command name—and so _will_ see your wrapper. However, the only Eclipse desktop files I have are in the format specified in the question—giving a full path to the Eclipse binary.

Comment: @Auspex: Well, the one which is provided in the Ubuntu archive (up to 18.10) has `Exec=eclipse`. But I agree, if `.desktop` specifies a full path, my answer does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with kmenuedit. It never saves the "Environment Variable" field in the .desktop file. Hope this helps. I opened a bug with KDE. "FOO=my_var_1" never gets saved, and never gets sent to the app.