# Use AMD/Intel switchable graphics program on specific programs like in Windows?

Tags: drivers, 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics, radeon

thanks for viewing.

I am dual-booting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS_x64 along Winodws 8.1_x64 with:

Processor: Intel Core i7-3635QM and Intel HD4000 integrated chip

AMD Radeon HD 8770M

In windows, the AMD switchable graphics program lets me choose which programs use 
which video card, but in Ubuntu it seems I can only download the catalyst control center which lets me choose which graphics card to use all the time unless I go and change it. I installed the fglrx package and then the fglrx-update, that didn't work so I had to install the lastest drivers for the AMD card straight from AMD's website. That lets me open the control center, is this the only thing I can get for Ubuntu? Is there any way that I can choose which programs use which card?

Comment: Based on my own tests, it does not appear that this function exists in the Linux drivers...

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with Catalyst Control Center:

[image]

To install open your Terminal and execute:

> sudo apt-get install fglrx

Then give a restart.

### If you have trouble setting up visit [Ubuntu/AMD Binary Driver Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Manually_installing_Catalyst_13.4.2C_special_case_for_Intel.2BAC8-AMD_hybrid_graphics)

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question asked by the asker.  The asker asks, specifically, to be able to control which GPU is used by individual programs.  Under Windows, you can specifically define whether the high-performance GPU is in use or if the power-saving GPU is in use for individual programs (such as one setting for Chrome and Flash player, with another setting for Firefox, another setting for Counter-Strike: Source, etc.).  I don't believe this function that the OP is seeking actually exists in the Linux version of the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern system ([see here for more details](https://askubuntu.com/a/469439/16395)), at least when **using the open source radeon drivers**, you should be able to use the environment variable `DRI_PRIME`. Check if it works by monitoring the difference between

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
```

and

```
glxgears -info
```

I do not know if this thing is supposed to work with `fglrx` proprietary drivers.

If it works, you can add it to the `.desktop` file of the application you want to use the discrete GPU: [Set variable in .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144968/set-variable-in-desktop-file)

More info can be also found in [Hybrid graphic card drivers (AMD® Radeon HD 8570 + Intel HD Graphics 4000)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593098/hybrid-graphic-card-drivers-amd-radeon-hd-8570-intel-hd-graphics-4000), and, as ever, [in the Arch Linux documentation pages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hybrid_graphics#ATI_Dynamic_Switchable_Graphics).

Comment: I don't believe this answers the OP's question fully, especially since they are probably working with GUI programs, not CLI as theri launchpoint

Comment: @ThomasW. --- if the DRI_PRIME works with proprietary drivers, it's just a matter of modifying the `.desktop` file to add the environment variable setting. http://askubuntu.com/questions/144968/set-variable-in-desktop-file