# Is my ubuntu using both video cards?

Tags: hybrid-graphics, gpu-driver

I got 2 videos cards, an intel hd 4000 onboard and a dedicated amd radeon 7730M.

Following this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card/503438#503438) that I answered myself, I could see that my computer was using the intel one.

However, the output today is:

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Chelsea LP [Radeon HD 7730M] [1002:682f] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

If it's using both video cards, how can I make it only use AMD when needed like it should be, to save battery power?

maybe some useful info: i'm using Xorg driver and tlp in battery mode didn't change anything

Comment: Thanks! :-)  I'm sorry that I couldn't be of more help...

Comment: And double thanks now that the grace period has ended...  If there is anything I can do for you in the future, just drop by in the AskUbuntu General Room with a link to this Q, and I'll help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to like this answer:

AMD's Dynamic Switchable Graphics needs Xorg support for the discrete videocard assigned for rendering to work. So, rendering on the discrete gpu will not work until the Xorg team adds support for it.

But you've still got three options:

1. Use the BIOS to disable the discrete card and use only the Intel IGPU / enable the discrete card when you really need it and use only the AMD DGPU (this is how I run, it just takes a reboot and you'll get used to it)
2. Test and improve some virtualGL based program to make the switch, like the common-amd branch of [Bumblebee project](http://bumblebee-project.org/). Check the [project repository](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/52) and [this useful post](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-909802.html).
3. Use the proprietary driver with powerxpress (a.k.a. pxp) support maintained by [Vi0l0](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMD_Catalyst#Installing_from_the_AUR) (remember to check for xorg compatibility).

[<sub>Source</sub>](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hybrid_graphics)

Answer (score 0):

When you use proprietary AMD/ATI driver with Catalyst you can choose what Videocard can you use. [Here is another answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473661/use-amd-intel-switchable-graphics-program-on-specific-programs-like-in-windows)