# How to get Telegram to show up in Dash

Tags: unity-dash, telegram

I have downloaded Telegram Messenger for PC/Mac/Linux from their [website](http://telegram.org) and copied it to `/opt/Telegram/Telegram`. After that i have created a sym link in `/usr/local/bin` that points to the installation directroy and added it to my PATH. Now i can easily start Telgram Messenger from console but how do i get it indexed by Dash including the app icon?

Comment: Haven't used Telegram desktop but you probably need a .desktop file. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The programs that show up in the Dash, desktop menus etc are there due to `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` & `~/.local/share/applications`. You can easily make a launcher using a file similar to this in either of the above locations (named `telegram.desktop` or similar):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Telegram
Exec=/opt/Telegram/Telegram -- %u
Icon=/opt/Telegram/telegram128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/tg;
```

Note that the `Exec` line should contain the command to launch the app (like the one you used in Terminal) - this can be like `telegram`, `/usr/bin/telegram-cli`, `/opt/Telegram/Telegram` etc.

The `Icon` line points to the icon to use - this can be `telegram` (if there is are appropriately named icons in `~/.local/share/icons` or `/usr/share/applications`), or point to a icon file directly. (e.g. `/opt/Telegram/telegram128.png`.). If you need a icon I have uploaded one [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO565.png).

If the file does not show, try running  one of these commands:

```
update-desktop-database /usr/share/applications
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
```

depending on where you placed the file. A restart of the desktop (or logging out and back in again) may be necessary. A similar process can be done for other applications.

The spec for a .desktop file can be found here: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/

Comment: Thx! Telegram already added a .desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications. But the exec part looked like exec=-- $u. I changed it to exec=/opt/Telegram/Telegram %u and it worked.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @Nurlan how so? Telegram will need to be installed, and you need to configure the `Exec` and `Icon` lines.

Comment: @Wilf, The file existed in system. After editing it and restarting the OS  I could find icon in dash. Thanks!

Comment: How to call it with  `QT_IM_MODULE=xim` option in .desktop, because I'm getting errors with accents.

Comment: @Sigur stick if at the beginning after `Exec=env` (probably...) or use a bash script EDIT: https://askubuntu.com/q/144968/178596

Answer (score 4):

Also you can [install Telegram](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-telegram-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) using `snap` (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
$ sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```