# Dark theme on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, themes

The dark theme on Ubuntu 20.04 is simply unusable and, frankly, I wonder how it ended up in the release.

This the application eclipse using its "light theme":

[image]

It is unreadable. I have the same problem with other applications, like, e.g., Zotero.

Is there a way to keep using the ubuntu dark theme and keep reading what is on the screen?

Comment: change your Eclipse theme.

Comment: Also please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1417606/edit) your question to remove rants about Ubuntu's dark theme and instead focus on what the problem is that you want fixed.

Comment: Aside from that, Ubuntu just reports that you have a dark theme selected on an OS level to the applications. It is the applications themselves that decide what to do about that, and apparently some applications handle it remarkably terribly. That has nothing to do with Ubuntu though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse looks terrible with Linux Dark Theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149986/eclipse-looks-terrible-with-linux-dark-theme)

Comment: @Esther Sorry, but I do not understand. I have Ubuntu set to Dark theme and Eclipse set to light theme. The same problem occurs with other applications, set to "light", but using these absurd colors.

Comment: That is a bug/problem in the application; there is nothing Ubuntu can do about it. You have to change your settings in the application(s) so that the text is readable. If that isn't possible, then contact the developer(s) of the applications and submit bug reports to them.

Comment: for Eclipse specifically, the duplicate question has some solutions to be able to read/use eclipse normally.