# Can I make just GIMP use a dark theme?

Tags: themes, gimp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I apply a different GTK3 theme from the main one to an individual application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio)

When doing color work with photos it can be useful to have a dark background and GUI elements. Several photo editing applications provide this natively:

[image: Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 4] [image: Apple Aperture 3] [image: darktable]

I've seen screenshots of GIMP with a dark color theme that approximates this effect:

[image: GIMP 2.8 with dark theme]

Can I make GIMP look like this without affecting other applications?

Comment: No, this is a specific question about Gimp, which is a gtk2 program at the moment, whether we are taking about version 2.6 or 2.8.

Comment: I suppose the question is a bit specific, but the answer for this is actually in there.

Answer (score 3):

There is one `gtk2` theme that I use for `gimp 2.6`, although it should work for `gimp 2.8`, and that is `Darkilouche`. (It will work until `gimp` switches to `gtk3` around the time of `gimp` 3.) It may not be *quite* as dark as the one you have in mind, but it's good and you may be able to modify it further. It was created by a while ago [here](http://jimmac.musichall.cz/log/?p=8) and the version you want is 0.2.3, available [here](http://jimmac.musichall.cz/zip/Darkilouche-0.2.3.tar.bz2) as well.

Needless to say, it is easy to install. Just unpack the zip and create a new folder called `Darkilouche` and place in it the contents of the zip (folders labelled `gtk-2.0`, `.svn` and a file named `Darkilouche`. Then move the `Darkilouche` folder to `.themes` in your home folder. Then, to test it with `gimp` (substituting `gimp-2.6` for your version), run:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=$HOME/.themes/Darkilouche/gtk-2.0/gtkrc gimp-2.6
```

This command simply specifies a particular theme (`gtkrc`) to use with a `gtk` application, it will NOT affect your general Ubuntu theme or interfere with any other programs.

Then you can create a launcher to run `gimp` like this in the future.

[image]
[image]