# How to use a different gtk (gtk3) theme for some applications?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, gtk3, customization

I want to use a custom theme for Nautilus and for some other applications but I want to keep the generic theme for the rest of the applications and system.

I know it can be done in gtk2.

For example the theme I'm using now uses a dark theme for the terminal and the image viewer and the rest of applications that look clear with it.

Is there a simple way to do it, like setting a path to a existing theme for each application I want to customize?

I hope you know what I mean, my english isn't that good.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I apply a different GTK3 theme from the main one to an individual application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio)