# Creating a launcher entry about an app in home directory which needs "GTK2_RC_FILES" to run

Tags: 12.10, launcher

I have installed(extracted) ADT(Android Developer Tools) at my home directory and I want to have a launcher icon for it.

**Reason for this:**
I have the problem with the dark tooltips at eclipse and I'm trying the fix described [here](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120728/how-to-fix-eclipse-colors-for-autocompletion-and-tooltips/) so I need to run eclipse with `GTK2_RC_FILES=~/.gtkrc-eclipse` everytime.
*(Also, I am using medditeraneanDark theme if that's needed as info.)*

This is what I have created and works:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ADT
Exec=/home/chris/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/chris/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_22.0.1.v201305230001--685705/icons/adt.png
Type=Application
```

But now I need to run adt like this:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=~/.gtkrc-eclipse /home/chris/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/eclipse/eclipse
```

I've tried these:

```
Exec=GTK2_RC_FILES=~/.gtkrc-eclipse /home/chris/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/eclipse/eclipse

Exec="GTK2_RC_FILES=~/.gtkrc-eclipse /home/chris/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/eclipse/eclipse"
```

But none seemed to work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @downvoter: could you at least point out why you're downvoting?!

Comment: Chris, see if http://askubuntu.com/q/78088/25656 helps you. (Fixed faulty link!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with the `env` command

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env GTK2_RC_FILES=/home/chris/.gtkrc-eclipse /home/chris/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/eclipse/eclipse
```

See `man env`

```
NAME
       env - run a program in a modified environment

SYNOPSIS
       env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
```

Comment: I tried this and it does run but the icons of Eclipse don't show and the settings of gtkr-eclipse haven't been applied. Running this command at terminal though everything looks as wanted `GTK2_RC_FILES=$HOME/.gtkrc-eclipse /home/chris/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/eclipse/eclipse`

Comment: Hmm... sorry - maybe try absolute path `/home/chris` instead or `$HOME`

Comment: OK that's good - I have corrected the answer accordingly