# Force Mendeley Desktop GTK theme

Tags: 14.04, themes, gtk, mendeley

I've been trying for a while to set the GTK theme of the Mendeley desktop UI, without success. The reason I want to do this is because I am using [a dark theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/DeLorean-Dark-Themes), and that Mendeley is unreadable (dark font on dark bg) with this theme. The two relevant sources of information I'm using are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio) and [here](http://worldofgnome.org/running-gtk-applications-different-themes-per-app/).

They both basically say that calling an executable like so

```
$ GTK_THEME=MyFancyTheme my_stubborn_app
```

should override the default GTK theme for the current user, and that permanent theme changes can be integrated in the `.../share/my_stubborn_app.desktop` by altering the `EXEC` line:

```
Exec=env GTK_THEME=MyFancyTheme /path/to/my_stubborn_app %u
```

---

None of these methods works in my case.
The special things about Mendeley desktop UI on Ubuntu (Trusty Tahr 14.04, Mendeley UI v1.14 in my case) are:

- It comes as a standalone package with its own `bin` and `share` and `lib` folders and it uses Qt.
- The actual binary is in `lib/mendeleydesktop/libexec/mendeleydesktop.x86_64` (for Ubuntu 64 bits) but cannot be called directly because it requires environment variables defined by the python script `bin/mendeleydesktop`.
- The `mendeleydesktop.desktop` file (which allows having an icon in the Unity launcher) is overwritten by `bin/install-mendeley-link-handler.sh` each time `bin/mendeleydesktop` is called.
- This `mendeleydesktop.desktop` file is created/overwritten in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`.

What I did so far was to edit `bin/install-mendeley-link-handler.sh` so that the `.desktop` file overwritten at each call would include the modified `Exec=env GTK_THEME...` line. That doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to get it done, although it feels a bit clunky. In the following:

- `$MENDELEY_FOLDER` is the Mendeley folder,
- `$CURRENT_GTK_THEME` is the name of the GTK theme you are currently using
- `$MENDELEY_GTK_THEME` is the name of the theme you'd like to use with Mendeley

NOTE: To get the name of the theme that you are currently using, type `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme` in a terminal. A good theme to be using with Mendeley is `Ambiance`.

#### Create a new themes directory

We will essentially trick Mendeley into thinking that the root GTK themes folder is somewhere else.

```
mkdir $MENDELEY_FOLDER/share/themes/
ln -s  /usr/share/themes/$MENDELEY_GTK_THEME  $MENDELEY_FOLDER/share/themes/$CURRENT_GTK_THEME
```

#### Modify the script `install-mendeley-link-handler.sh`

It should be located in `$MENDELEY_FOLDER/bin/install-mendeley-link-handler.sh`.
You need to edit the lines that overwrite the file `mendeleydesktop.desktop`, in my case:

```
cat > $DESKTOP_PATH/mendeleydesktop.desktop <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mendeley Desktop
GenericName=Research Paper Manager
Comment=Mendeley Desktop is software for managing and sharing research papers
Exec=env GTK_DATA_PREFIX=$MENDELEY_FOLDER $MENDELEYDESKTOP_BIN %u
Icon=mendeleydesktop
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Education;Literature;Qt;
X-SuSE-translate=false;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mendeley;application/pdf;text/x-bibtex;
X-Mendeley-Version=1
EOF
```

Notice the change in the `Exec=...` line.

#### Create a new mendeley executable

Wherever you keep your local binaries (eg `$HOME/local/bin`), create a new file `mendeley` with the following:

```
GTK_DATA_PREFIX=$MENDELEY_FOLDER \
    $MENDELEY_FOLDER/bin/mendeleydesktop
```

Then make it executable by running `chmod +x mendeley`, and run it in order to update the `mendeleydesktop.desktop` file.

#### If you installed Mendeley system-wide

The last step is only slightly different, in that the system-wide script (most likely located in `/opt/mendeleydesktop`) actually creates a link to the `mendeleydesktop` executable in `$HOME/.local/share`, and that is what the previous script needs to call instead.

#### Applying those changes to the Unity icon

The file to edit should be `/usr/share/applications/mendeleydesktop.desktop`.
In this file, you should modify the `Exec` line as previously, by prefixing the call with the definition of `GTK_DATA_PREFIX`. This should do the trick :)

Comment: confirm! works with new gnome too, default `Adwaita` also looks good

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive writeup! Would you mind sharing a screenshot to show what it looks like before I jump in?

Comment: Hi, Thnaks for your tutorial. This is not working for me. Can you kindly check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438437/dark-theme-for-mendeley

Comment: @BaRud You should read more carefully. The target of a link is not the same as its name. And your env-var is wrongly set.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add an answer that has worked well for me on kde plasma (manjaro linux). It does *not* require any admin rights.

**disclaimer:** only tested once on my system on 2018-12-04 with Mendeley 1.19,
 commands below and results may vary with different DE and/or OS or different Mendeley version.

1. create an empty folder, e.g.
    `mkdir $HOME/.config.theme_override`.
2. symlink your Mendeley config to the new folder:
    `ln -s "$HOME/.config/Mendeley Ltd." "$HOME/.config.theme_override/Mendeley Ltd."`
3. start mendeleydesktop from the command line using:
    `XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config.theme_override" mendeleydesktop`

Then mendeley will look for plasma theme settings in `$HOME/.config.theme_override`, it will not find any theme and fall back to the readable bright theme.

Now the desktop entry:

1. make sure mendeley is **closed**
2. edit the file `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mendeleydesktop.desktop` to look like (**) below
3. remove write permission from the `.desktop` file:
    
   `chmod -w $HOME/.local/share/applications/mendeleydesktop.desktop`
4. start mendeleydesktop from the app launcher and gaze at the clear and readable interface.

A few notes/insights to help future detectives:

- The default Mendeley config folder is `$HOME/.config/Mendeley Ltd.`, changing your config folder does not change where the Mendeley database is located (`$HOME/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd.`).
- Mendeley also stores some data in `$HOME/.local/share/Mendeley Ltd.` and `$HOME/.cache/Mendeley Ltd.`, changing the config folder does not change where Mendeley looks for these folders. It looks like these folders can be removed without risk and Mendeley will restore them automatically. If the stuff above does not work for changing the theme, then maybe removing these folders can help, but I'm not sure, proceed at your own risk.
- Each time Mendeley is started, a script is run to override the `.desktop` file, which is the file that makes mendeley show up in application menus and launchers. This why we needed step (3.) above. This file is located at: `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mendeleydesktop.desktop`, it will execute the file `$HOME/.local/share/mendeleydesktop`, which by default is symlinked to `/opt/mendeleydesktop/bin/mendeleydesktop`. Don't ask me why Mendeley developers chose this complicated setup.

(** contents of `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mendeleydesktop.desktop`)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mendeley Desktop
GenericName=Research Paper Manager
Comment=Mendeley Desktop is software for managing and sharing research papers
Exec=env XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config.theme_override" $HOME/.local/share/mendeleydesktop %f
Icon=mendeleydesktop
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Education;Literature;Qt;
X-SuSE-translate=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mendeley;application/pdf;text/x-bibtex;
X-Mendeley-Version=1
```

Comment: This fix worked great for me for several months. It seems a recent Mendeley update (1.19.4) seems to have broken it again unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, I used this fix again today with mendeley 1.19.4 on kubuntu 19.10 and it still worked. So it might be worth giving it another try :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a slightly different way.
My KDE Plasma style was set as Breeze Dark with some custom font size settings. I wanted mendeleydesktop to use all these font size settings but not the dark color settings.

As suggested in the posts above, I created an empty folder:

```
mkdir $HOME/.config.theme_override
```

Then, I run

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config.theme_override" mendeleydesktop
```

...to see which folders it will use on default in its config folder. It turned out that, in my case, mendeleydesktop created three new folders in `$HOME/.config.theme_override`:

```
libreoffice  'Mendeley Ltd.'   pulse
```

I removed these new folders:

```
rmdir libreoffice

rmdir 'Mendeley Ltd.'

rmdir pulse
```

and I replaced them with symlinks to the corresponding old folders in `$HOME/.config`:

```
ln -s "$HOME/.config/Mendeley Ltd." "$HOME/.config.theme_override/Mendeley Ltd."

ln -s "$HOME/.config/libreoffice" "$HOME/.config.theme_override/libreoffice"

ln -s "$HOME/.config/pulse" "$HOME/.config.theme_override/pulse"
```

Next, I copied the `kdeglobals` file from `$HOME/.config` to `$HOME/.config.theme_override`:

```
cp $HOME/.config/kdeglobals $HOME/.config.theme_override/
```

Finally, I removed all sections about colors from `$HOME/.config.theme_override/kdeglobals`:

```
[ColorEffects:Inactive]
ChangeSelectionColor=true
Color=112,111,110
ColorAmount=0.025
ColorEffect=2
ContrastAmount=0.1
ContrastEffect=2
Enable=false
IntensityAmount=0
IntensityEffect=0

[Colors:Button]
BackgroundAlternate=77,77,77
BackgroundNormal=49,54,59
DecorationFocus=61,174,233
DecorationHover=61,174,233
ForegroundActive=61,174,233
ForegroundInactive=189,195,199
ForegroundLink=41,128,185
ForegroundNegative=218,68,83
ForegroundNeutral=246,116,0
ForegroundNormal=239,240,241
ForegroundPositive=39,174,96
ForegroundVisited=127,140,141

[Colors:Complementary]
BackgroundAlternate=59,64,69
BackgroundNormal=49,54,59
DecorationFocus=30,146,255
DecorationHover=61,174,230
ForegroundActive=246,116,0
ForegroundInactive=175,176,179
ForegroundLink=61,174,230
ForegroundNegative=237,21,21
ForegroundNeutral=201,206,59
ForegroundNormal=239,240,241
ForegroundPositive=17,209,22
ForegroundVisited=61,174,230

[Colors:Selection]
BackgroundAlternate=29,153,243
BackgroundNormal=61,174,233
DecorationFocus=61,174,233
DecorationHover=61,174,233
ForegroundActive=252,252,252
ForegroundInactive=239,240,241
ForegroundLink=253,188,75
ForegroundNegative=218,68,83
ForegroundNeutral=246,116,0
ForegroundNormal=239,240,241
ForegroundPositive=39,174,96
ForegroundVisited=189,195,199

[Colors:Tooltip]
BackgroundAlternate=77,77,77
BackgroundNormal=49,54,59
DecorationFocus=61,174,233
DecorationHover=61,174,233
ForegroundActive=61,174,233
ForegroundInactive=189,195,199
ForegroundLink=41,128,185
ForegroundNegative=218,68,83
ForegroundNeutral=246,116,0
ForegroundNormal=239,240,241
ForegroundPositive=39,174,96
ForegroundVisited=127,140,141

[Colors:View]
BackgroundAlternate=49,54,59
BackgroundNormal=35,38,41
DecorationFocus=61,174,233
DecorationHover=61,174,233
ForegroundActive=61,174,233
ForegroundInactive=189,195,199
ForegroundLink=41,128,185
ForegroundNegative=218,68,83
ForegroundNeutral=246,116,0
ForegroundNormal=239,240,241
ForegroundPositive=39,174,96
ForegroundVisited=127,140,141

[Colors:Window]
BackgroundAlternate=77,77,77
BackgroundNormal=49,54,59
DecorationFocus=61,174,233
DecorationHover=61,174,233
ForegroundActive=61,174,233
ForegroundInactive=189,195,199
ForegroundLink=41,128,185
ForegroundNegative=218,68,83
ForegroundNeutral=246,116,0
ForegroundNormal=239,240,241
ForegroundPositive=39,174,96
ForegroundVisited=127,140,141
```

With the above sections removed, mendeleydesktop uses its own colors and not the KDE Plasma style colors but it uses all other style settings from `$HOME/.config.theme_override/kdeglobals`.

Answer (score 0):

A little update here:
A quick update solution to read in dark mode in Ubuntu now is using Gnome Extension Inverted Color.

[image]

Then, you can toggle the application screen between dark and light by Super + I

[image]