# Mendeley Dark mode on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mendeley

Has anyone found a way to have Mendeley on dark? It is quite disturbing on my full dark setup. Considering switching over to Zotero for this.

Appreciate any help.

Found this but it is a bit old, and I guess unrelated : [Force Mendeley Desktop GTK theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660529/force-mendeley-desktop-gtk-theme)

Comment: Did you find a good solution? I faced this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't. I even left Ubuntu for another distro, Mendeley for Zotero in between.