# Change GTK+3 icon theme for a specific application

Tags: themes, icons, customization, gtk3

[Firefox doesn't play well with dark system themes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519763) and I want to use  it and only it with a light system theme, which [can be done with an environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/a/485662/56267), but then it will still use my default icons for the menus, which are also light and turn almost invisible.

How to open a single GTK+3 program with a different icon theme? I've only found a [solution for GTK+2](https://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/setting-a-custom-gtk-theme-for-specific-applications/).

Comment: Is there any screenshot to show what you are actually seeing? If you mean similar to [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/M5Yfg8H.png) from the bugzilla thread, how to reproduce this issue? What are the themes used for the host system and Firefox?

Comment: @clearkimura I've already described the issue, and the specific themes are irrelevant to my question: "How to launch a single GTK-3 application with a separate icon theme, like it was possible with GTK-2?"

Comment: @clearkimura You've launched Firefox with another GTK-3 window border theme. I'm asking about icons.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
mkdir -p /home/$USER/.firefoxconfig
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/$USER/.firefoxconfig
lxappearance #or similar to select theme and icons
```

and then start firefox as:

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/$USER/.firefoxconfig firefox
```

As far as I know, firefox itself does not use the folder `~/.config`. If it does (or some other application for which you want to do the same as above), you might want to symlink relevant files/folders to `.firefoxconfig`.

Comment: I'm going to play around with this, I am using `~/.mozilla/firefox/theme` as my `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`