# Ubuntu 16.04 launch application with default theme

Tags: unity, themes, gtk

I am using ubuntu 16.04 with Delorean dark theme. 
I have installed a third party application and when I launch it there are some issues with the black theme (dark writings on dark background).
I would like to launch this application with the Default (light) theme.

I have looked around and tried https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1340828

[Can I apply a different GTK3 theme from the main one to an individual application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio)

The methods proposed there works with standard applications like gedit but not with that third party application. 
In the meanwhile I have found that If I launch the application with superuser privileges, it runs with the standard theme. 
Is there a way to make this application run with the standard theme without superuser privileges?

Comment: What was that _application_? Tell us the name

Comment: The application is Virtual NanoLab2016