# Change GTK theme for a single app

Tags: launcher, themes, gtk

I installed `gelemental` on my Xubuntu, which beautifully presents me the Periodic Table of Elements and gives information about each element.

However, on some themes (e.g Arc-s & Adwaita) the coloring is just non-existent, so I tried the methods [here (for a local launcher)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio) and [here (for the launcher in `/usr/...`)](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1340828) in order to change it to Greybird theme.

It doesn't seem to work for me after all though. can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Here is the local launcher I created (I tried spelling greybird with a lowercase 'g' as well, I made sure it looks how it want if I change the main theme itself to Greybird in the Appearence Setting):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Periodic Table
Comment=View the periodic table of elements
Exec=env GTK_THEME=Greybird gelemental
Icon=gelemental
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

And the launcher in `/usr/share/applications/` (The original is now `*.bakup`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Periodic Table
...
Name[<Misc Languages>]=<Some Name>
...
Comment=View the periodic table of elements
...
Comment[<Misc Languages>]=<Some Description>
...
Exec=bash -c 'GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc gelemental'
Icon=gelemental
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;Education;Science;Chemistry;
```

UPDATE: I found it probably has something to do with the XFCE special theming - but it's still weird, because the theming has to do with xfwm and the problem occurs when I switch it to Openbox as well (via `openbox --replace`). I still couldn't fix it in either of the two

Comment: What version of Xubuntu are you on? Maybe you could upload an image of what you mean by "the coloring is just non-existent". Does gelemental display properly with _any_ theme? If so, which one(s)?

Comment: I use the Xubuntu 16.04, but installed the `xubuntu-core` rather than `xubuntu-desktop` if it matters. Like with the example, the elements' background is colourful (colour depends on series) with Greybird theme but only grey with Arc-dark