# stop apps from following new Ubuntu themes

Tags: themes

so I was wondering if there's any way to stop a specific app from following a new theme you apply to Ubuntu because as you may encounter some apps are not compatible with dark themes and not usable when you change your theme I wanted to know if there's any way to fix that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I apply a different GTK3 theme from the main one to an individual application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio)

Comment: In the [highest voted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/485662/167115) it shows how to use the theme "elementary" for the application "pantheon-files" but you can use any theme with any application. Also, you can use the actual path to the theme you want to use instead of the theme name as outlined in one of the comments.

Comment: Please let us know if that doesn't work. I just tried this and it doesn't change the "window theme" but it does seem to change the gtk theme of the app itself.

Comment: It will all depend on the toolkit that the app uses. Answer marked as "duplicate" is for GTK3, and will not work for GTK2 or QT or whatever else.