# Changing environment variables for a specific program Ubuntu 20.04, Gurps GCS using Java

Tags: 20.04, java, themes, environment-variables

I'm using a program to make GURPS characters (this is a game basically like D&D, with a lot more flexibility) created and run over here:

https://gurpscharactersheet.com/

It's made in Java, and currently, when I open it, it renders all of the text invisible unless I click on an option. (See the screenshot.)

Corresponding with the developer, he's saying that the dark theme I'm using is contributing to the unreadable quality. I can confirm this after playing with that option!

There is a theme option in the program, but nothing in those options controls the basic presentation of text in selection.

They also suggested opening GCS with a different environment variable setting, but I'm not sure what to change.

I've investigated the option but most of what I've found involves changing the entire desktop environment, not just the variables for one program.

I would love to know how to change the environment options just for this program!

[image: Example of the text invisible unless currently selected.]

Comment: It does! Thank you very much. I've added it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user68186 Shared this with me, which didn't turn up in my search:

[Can I apply a different GTK3 theme from the main one to an individual application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio)

The top answer worked for me, but the shorthand is that you create a custom .desktop file in your local/share/applications folder and apply a different theme to the launching of that particular app!

I chose a light theme instead of a dark one for the GCS app and it works fine!

FYI: Spelling is important when including your theme choice.