# Is there any way to turn off Dark mode for some specific apps in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, appearance

I have turned on Dark mode for my system and i loved it but there are some apps in which I want it in light mode. Is there any way to get the system in dark mode and some specific apps in light mode ?

Comment: Only if the applications themselves have themes that can override the OS theming 

Comment: otherwise I need to turn off Dark mode for the system also ?

Comment: If all the applications you want happened to use one toolkit (eg. Qt) but your desktop used another (GTK+) you could in theory have a light Qt theme selected, and dark GTK+ theme... but you've given no specific examples so this may not apply (and you'd have to be pretty lucky for all applications to align that perfectly)

Comment: For GTK3 applications, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio/485662#485662