# Dark mode specific apps on ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

I recently downloaded one note for linux on my ubuntu.

My problem is that there is no option for dark mode in it and it is too bright.

Is there an option to only enable dark mode for specific apps, in my case one note?

Comment: I don't know if GNOME Shell has this option, but I'm using Compiz and in Compiz you can switch any application window to negative by pressing <Super>+N (maybe it needs to be enabled in Compiz settings, I don't remember if it was enabled by default) - this gives you temporarily sort of a "dark mode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no, if the application does not expose an option.

It actually depends in case of other applications. For example, it can easily be done for any GTK3 application (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio)). Other toolkits (e.g. QT5, ...) may also have specific methods. However, in this case you are dealing with a proprietary app, probably using web technology in an elektron wrapper, with no exposed methods to change the theme that is used.